# Any idea what's wrong with this d3 sort function?

Tags: sorting, d3.js, graph

I'm desperately trying to add a simple sort function (alphabetical order) to my bar graph, but strangely all the bars seem to disappear to the left when i click (triggers the sort function).

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code ?

Here's the snippet:

```
//I would like to sort the bars just by clicking on the title
        title.on("click", function () {sortBars()});

        var sortBars = function() {svg.selectAll("rect")
                                      .sort(function(a, b) {
                                               return d3.ascending(a.Region, b.Region); })
                                      .transition()
                                      .duration(1000)
                                      .attr("x", function(d, i) {return xScale(i);});};


                    //Title
                    title = svg.append("text")
                       .attr("x", (svgWidth / 2))
                       .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
                       .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                       .attr("font-family", "futura")
                       .style("fill", "#5a5a5a")
                       .text("Nombre d'observations par régions");
```

Here's a screenshot of the graph after the sort function is triggered: [all bars to the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hmri.png)

The csv file i'm calling has 2 columns, one called `Classification` (containing numbers) and the other one `Region` (containing names of different regions)

Any help would be much appreciated ! Thank you

Edit: here is the full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <title>D3 Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
        div.tooltip {position: absolute;            
                     text-align: center;            
                     width: none;                   
                     height: none;                  
                     padding: none;             
                     font: 12px futura;
                     color: thistle;        
                     background: none;  
                     border: 0px;       
                     border-radius: 8px;            
                     pointer-events: none;}

        svg {background-color: none;}


        .tooltip {font: 10px futura;
                  color: thistle;}


        .axisX line{stroke: white;}
        .axisX path{stroke: white;}
        .axisX text{fill: black;}  

        .axisY line{stroke: black;}
        .axisY path{stroke: white;}


        .horizontalGrid line {stroke: lightgrey;
                              stroke-opacity: 0;
                              shape-rendering: crispEdges;}
        .horizontalGrid path {stroke-width: 0;}



        </style>
        <script type ="text/javascript" src = d3/d3.js></script>
        <script>

        //Variables; dimensions du canevas
        var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 130, left: 120},
            svgWidth = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            svgHeight = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
            barPadding = 2;

        //Variables: domaines de l'Axe X et Y
        var xScale = d3.scaleBand().range([0, svgWidth]).padding(0.1), //scaleBand pour des proportions
            yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([svgHeight, 0]); //scaleLinear pour des unités (noms, lettres)

        //Variable: échelle de couleur divisée en 80 nuances entre deux couleurs
        var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,80]).range(["white",  "mediumturquoise"]);

        //Variable: création du canevas dans <body>
        var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", svgWidth + margin.left + margin.right)
                        .attr("height", svgHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        //Variable: petit encadré qui apparait au passage de la souris
        var div = d3.select("body")
                        .append("div")
                        .attr("class", "tooltip")
                        .style("visibility", "hidden");

        var absoluteView = false


        //Variable: format des nombre lors de la transition de chargement des nombres -> https://github.com/d3/d3-format
        var format = d3.format("d"); //d = notation décimale arrondie aux entiers




        //Biding: 
        d3.csv("/Users/daumardlouis/Desktop/geid3.csv", function(error, data) {if (error) throw error;

            data.forEach(function(d) {d.Classification = +d.Classification;});

            xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.Region}));
            yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data,function(d) {return d.Classification})]);




            //Définition des barres
            rect = svg.selectAll("rect")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", function(d) {return xScale(d.Region)})
                .attr("width", svgWidth / data.length - barPadding)
                .attr("y", svgHeight) // écart de l'axe Y = hauteur du canevas SVG
                .attr("height", 0) // hauteur de départ des barres à 0 pour l'effet de transition
                .attr("fill", function (d) {return colorScale (d.Classification)})
                .style("opacity", 0.9)
                .on("mouseover",function(d) {d3.select(this).style("fill", "thistle").style("opacity", 0.5); // rempli de couleur la barre au passage de la souris
                                             div.transition() // affiche le div en 0.2 secondes avec opacité de .5
                                                .duration(200)
                                                .style("visibility", "hidden");
                                             div.html(d.Classification) // affiche une donnée ou un texte dans le div
                                                 .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 50) + "px") 
                                                 .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 70) + "px"); // la hauteur du div par rapport à la souris (attention en html la hauteur est inversée)
                                             if(!absoluteView) {
                                                var xPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x")) + 6;
                                                var yPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) + 2;
                                                var height = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("height"));
                                                svg.append("text")
                                                .attr("x", xPos)
                                                .attr("y", yPos - 10)
                                                .attr("class", "tooltip")
                                                .text(d.Classification)
                                                .attr("fill", "thistle")};



                                    })

                .on("mouseout",function(d) {d3.select(this).transition().duration(150).style("fill", function (d) {return colorScale (d.Classification)}).style("opacity", 1); // renvoie la couleur initiale à la sortie de la souris
                                            div.transition() // faire disparaitre la div après .5 secondes
                                                .duration(200)
                                                .style("visibility", "hidden")
                                            svg.select(".tooltip").remove();

                                            });

            //Transition des barres (rect)
            rect.transition()
                .delay(1000)
                .ease(d3.easePoly)
                .duration(500)
                .attr("y", function(d) {return yScale(d.Classification)})
                .attr("height", function(d) {return svgHeight - yScale(d.Classification)}); 



            //Transition: effet de chargement progressif des nombres 
            var texte = svg.selectAll("text")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .text(0) //texte à 0 au départ de la transition
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {return 8 + i * (svgWidth / data.length)})
            .attr("y", svgHeight) // commence à 0, cad à la hauteur du canevas 
            .attr("fill", "thistle")
            .attr("font-family", "futura")
            .attr("font-size", "10px")
            .transition()
            .delay(function(d,i){return i *30}) //ajouter un délai décalé pour chaque élément de data
            .ease(d3.easePoly)
            .duration(900)
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {return 8 + i * (svgWidth / data.length)})
            .attr("y", function(d) {return yScale(d.Classification) + (yScale(svgHeight) / 16) })
            .tween("text", function(d) {var that = d3.select(this),
                                            i = d3.interpolateNumber(that.text(), d.Classification); //donner une val de départ et de fin
                                            return function(t) {that.text(format(i(t)))}}) //retourne le texte au format défini plus haut
            .transition()
            .delay(function(d,i){return 500 + i * (-30)}) //delay de 500 + annulation du délai décalé
            .style("opacity", 0);


            //Axe X, son style et ses transitions
            var axeX = svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axisX") // récupère les indications de style de .axisX à l'interieur de la balise <style>. Utile pour changer la couleur de l'axe
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + svgHeight + ")")
                .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickSize(0)) //marqueur d'échelle de taille 0
                .selectAll("text")
                .attr("display", "true")
                .attr("font-size", 2)
                .attr("dx", "-4.8em")
                .attr("dy", "4.15em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end") //centre la fin du texte au milieu de chaque barre (rect)
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)") //effectue une rotation de -65°
                .transition()
                .duration(500)
                .delay(function(d,i){return i *30})
                .attr("font-family", "futura", "Bold")
                .attr("font-size", 10); //style de police de caractère




            //Axe Y, son style et ses transitions
            var axeY = svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axisY")
                .attr("transform", "translate(-5)")
                .transition()
                .duration(5000)
                .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickSize(3))
                .selectAll("text")
                .attr("transform", "translate(-5)")
                .attr("font-family", "futura")
                .attr("fill", "thistle");   //couleur de police de caractère



            //Rajoute une légende à laxe Y
             svg.append("g")
             .append("text")
             .attr("font-family", "futura")
             .attr("font-size", 10)
             .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
             .attr("y", -48)
             .attr("x", -68)
             .style("text-anchor", "end")
             .text("");



            //Rajoute des lignes de fonds prolongeant l'axe Y
             svg.selectAll("axisY")
                .data(yScale)
                .enter()
                .append("line")
                .attr("class", "horizontalGrid")
                .attr("x1", 0)
                .attr("x2", svgWidth)
                .attr("y1", function(d){ return yScale(d);})
                .attr("y2", function(d){ return yScale(d);});



          //I would like to sort the bars just by clicking on the title
             title.on("click", function () {sortBars()});




             var sortBars = function() {
                        svg.selectAll("rect")
                           .sort(function(a, b) {
                                       return d3.ascending(a.Region, b.Region); })
                              .transition()
                              .duration(1000)
                              .attr("x", function(d, i) {return xScale(i);});};


            //Title
            title = svg.append("text")
               .attr("x", (svgWidth / 2))
               .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
               .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
               .attr("font-family", "futura")
               .style("fill", "#5a5a5a")
               .text("Nombre d'observations par régions");





       });
        </script>
    <body>
</html>
```

Edit 2: Very strangely, the x Axis (here called `axeX`) is not redrawn when i `.call(xAxis)`. If i apply another transformation, like changing the color of the x Axis, it works but only the sorting function seem not to operate.

The only solution I found is to `select(".axisX")`(in the CSS) instead of `axeX` and then calling `(xAxis)`. However the `Region`s' names are all messed-up ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMmGA.png))

Here is what the code looks like

```
  // Redraw x Axis 
                d3.select(".axisX")
                    .transition()
                    .duration(1000)
                    .call(xAxis)
```

instead of:

```
  // Redraw x Axis
                axeX.transition()
                    .duration(1000)
                    .call(xAxis)
```

Any idea why the calling of the xAxis doesn't work with `axeX` ? And why the positions of the names on the x Axis are all messed up with my code ?

Comment: It's hard to know what's happening without seeing more code. Can you show us the code where you actually build the graph.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I just updated my question with the full code...the sorting function is at the very end.

Comment: @solub This question has an accepted (by you) answer already. If you have another problem, post **another** question.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I'll ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the basic idea is that you want to sort the domain of the x scale and redraw with that scale. You can do something like this:

```
var sortBars = function() {
    // Change domain based on sorted data
    xScale.domain(data.sort(function(a, b) {
        return  d3.ascending(a.Region, b.Region);
        })
        .map(function(d) {return d.Region})
    )

    // Redraw Rects with new position
    svg.selectAll("rect")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {return xScale(d.Region)})

    // Redraw x Axis
    axeX.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .call(xAxis)
```

It looks like you are doing some styling on the X axis, so you may need to reapply styles.

EDIT: 
Also, I would save a reference to the xAxis so you can call it later:

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickSize(0)
```

and replace the `.call()` with this:

```
var axeX = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axisX") // récupère les indications de style de .axisX à l'interieur de la balise <style>. Utile pour changer la couleur de l'axe
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + svgHeight + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
```

instead of

```
var axeX = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axisX") // récupère les indications de style de .axisX à l'interieur de la balise <style>. Utile pour changer la couleur de l'axe
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + svgHeight + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickSize(0))
            //    ... etc.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to fix the problem and for your reply. I tried your code but unfortunately I've got an unknow type error for `.call(xAxis)`. I tried to replace it with `axeX` but it raises the same error message...

Comment: Oh, sorry, @solub, I forgot to mention, I pulled out the axis to it's easier to call it later. See the edit above.

Comment: Awesome ! The bars are sorting ! But the `Region`s' names don't change,  I still have to figure out how to sort them as well. Anyway, I don't want to bother you any longer. Thank you so much @Mark_M, you really made my day.

Comment: Very strangely, the x Axis is not redrawn when I call `xAxis`...no matter what i do. I edited my question with the details.